# Progress Bar to hide the page in till the page is loaded completely

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

My webpage takes anywhere from .5sec - 3 seconds to load completely.  I was just wondering if there was a way to have an overlay to show in till the page was loaded. When the page finished loading, I would want this overlay to hide.    Something like a progress bar or a .gif.  I'm using the razor engine in MVC3.

Comment: Don't do this; it's bad user experience.  Instead, [find ways](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) to make your page load quicker.

Comment: There are no users.  What this webpage is supposed to do is check for failed builds.  It will be on a Kiosk and it is when my animation happens, this is what causes the delay.  The animation is a scrollTo function to scroll any Div. that has a scroll box

Comment: In that case, why not use AJAX to load the build status?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5185865/643500

Comment: Also, http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/

Comment: hide your main content container and show some other div with a gif image, until you app is ready. When you know app is ready to just hide gif div and display the app div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things I have done to make this work: PS, Sorry for poor code blocks, new to all of this.

HTML Div:

```
<div id ="blocker">
<div>Loading...</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
#blocker{position: fixed;


top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #000;
z-index: 1000;  
opacity: 0.3;  
display: none;
```

}

```
#blocker div   
    { position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 5em;
    height: 2em;
    margin: -1em 0 0 -2.5em;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

JQuery before the Ajax gets called:

`$("#blocker").show();`

```
    $.ajax`
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do is:

```
var loadingTimeout;

$j('body').ajaxStart(function () {
    loadingTimeout= setTimeout(function () {
        $("#blocker").show();
    }, 1000);
});

$j('body').ajaxStop(function () {
    clearTimeout(loadingTimeout);
    $("#blocker").hide();
});
```

On every ajaxcall made in your page, your blocker gets displayed after 1 second. When the client gets the resonse, the block gets hidden again. What do yout think?

Comment: The way I set it up below is basically when the page is loading, it will keep the blocker up in till it is loaded.  Say the page takes half a millisecond to load, it will not display it; Though this will work having it display 1 second at a time, may not work 100% of the time, the Data may load slow.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one might help you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('button').click(function(){
      
        $('body').addClass('noscroll');
      
        document.querySelector("#overlay").classList.remove('is-visible');
 });
});
```

```css
#overlay {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #666666;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 25%;
  opacity: .80;
}

button {
  margin: 40px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.spinner {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 64px;
    width: 64px;
    animation: rotate 0.8s infinite linear;
    border: 5px solid firebrick;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
}


@keyframes rotate {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}


.is-visible {
 display: none;
}


.noscroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<body>

  <button>Load Spinner</button>

<div id="overlay" class="is-visible">
    <div class="spinner"></div>
    <br/>
    Loading...
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```